# Grabbing compiled filename hash from webpack compiler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am dynamically compiling a couple bundles in webpack to support some of my server-side rendering code. I need to inject the clientside bundle into the serverside generated HTML.

I have the clientside compiler reference and the only thing I need is the clientside bundle name (which includes a hash) `bundle.[hash].js` to support better caching. How can I access the compiled file name?

```
  const clientCompiler = webpack(client)
```

I've been looking at the stats object, but this bundle specifically is being ran through webpackdevserver manually.

```
 const webpackDevServer = new WebpackDevServer(
    clientCompiler,
    devServerConfiguration
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin and ripped it out of the stats object.

Comment: Hi, Can you please share how you solved it? I'm struggling of getting the filename with the hash